# Java Regex to find instances of "[" in a string

Tags: java, regex, uima

I'm currently working on a UIMA based project, and the data set I am using has some predefined plain-text annotations that I am trying to convert into UIMA annotations using the Matcher utility.

My problem is that the annotations are in the format [ANNO] [/ANNO], and I have no idea how to write '[' or ']' as a regular expression.

I tried searching various places, and couldn't find an answer to this, closest I could find is to use either the octal or hexidecimal value rendition, but I then can't actually find said rendition for the character.

Cheers

Comment: Escape them with \

Comment: So in a regex pattern, would that be '\\'?
Because Eclipse keeps telling me I can't escape them.

EDIT: OK, got the answer, Thanks a million and cheers! This was causing me to start tearing my hair out!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Dervall said, you must escape them:

```
Pattern pattern = pattern.compile("\\[");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("string to match against");
```

Comment: @rp.kelly You should probably accept the answer by pressing big button on the left.